# What is best in class defect found distribution?

Tags: metrics, data-analysis, kpi

Can people share a general target they have for % bugs found internally based on this equation: <# defects found internally> / <# internal defects + # customer found defects>

I realize this can vary for many reasons... waterfall, agile, cloud, appliance...

I have always strived for 90 - 95% internal found.  That was in a waterfall, appliance model.

I know this is nuanced.  And the adage "be careful what you measure" kicks in.
Still I am interested.

Note: I usually filter on a defect that requires a code fix.
Any thoughts on why that is (or is not) a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Highly recommend researching the theory behind the 6-sigma movement, such as [Defects per million metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defects_per_million_opportunities), suggested resources include [process sigma calculator (isixsigma.com)](https://www.isixsigma.com/process-sigma-calculator/) and [blog from field of quality control (westgard.com)](https://www.westgard.com/)

Strongly recommend moving beyond counting issue reports. There usually no relationship between issue reports and product quality (for many reasons ... duplicates, issue impact, works-as-designed)

In a perfect world where information is at our fingertips it would be possible to count all the production faults that have occurred or likely to occur, but AI isn't quite there yet and doing so manually is very time consuming.

Ultimately is balance between gutfeel (peoples experience) and quantitative numbers where you can get them.

One tip that have got people's attention for me is trace back them back to something the customer can relate to (eg. requirement):

- keep a Yes/No column indicating a customer report resulted in a fix
- keep a Yes/No column indicating a internal report resulted in a fix
- classify the source of the fault from a SDLC process perspective did it occur in design, build, test, system under tests capability,
- Ask around and estimate the time spent (raise, mitigate, resolving faults).
- Ask around and estimate the time inconvenience to the customers of your customer

From there you can review after 1 to 2 test cycles, decide what more granular data to include.